# SQL Server: How to return rounded value by removing zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the values in column 01 which i want to convert as values in Column 02, removing all the zero's from end. Is there a way to do this in SQL server ?

```
Column 01    Column 02 
20100000   201
29050000   2905
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: This is likely string handling, but not numeric values.

Comment: What is the datatype of those columns?

Comment: Data type is integer having field length of 4, can stored values between   -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Comment: @Ivan, that's right. These are not numeric values

Comment: ...not numeric but integer?

Comment: By the way, removing trailing zeros from an integer is not "rounding" it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For positive integers only you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col1 INT);
INSERT INTO #tab(col1) VALUES (20100000),(29050000);

SELECT col1, REVERSE(REVERSE(col1) + 0) + 0 AS trimmed
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/444199)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╗
║   Col1   ║ trimmed ║
╠══════════╬═════════╣
║ 20100000 ║     201 ║
║ 29050000 ║    2905 ║
╚══════════╩═════════╝
```

How it works:

1. Reverse number -> string
2. Add `0` -> implicit cast to `INT`. You could use `CAST/CONVERT` to be explicit !
3. Reverse one again -> string
4. Add `0` -> cast to `INT`

`20100000` -> `"0000102"` -> `102` -> `"201"` -> `201`

## Addendum

Added support for negative integer as well:

```
SELECT col1, SIGN(col1) * REVERSE(REVERSE(ABS(col1)) + 0) AS trimmed
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/444213)**</kbd>

Comment: This is good. But I wonder why do you prefer to perform implicit casts to int instead of just casting to int?

Comment: @Lamak I am a bit lazy. And the real reason is `+0` is shorter than `CAST` or `CONVERT` :)

Comment: @Lad.. It works for me ,, thanks for the quick help.. Hi5

Answer (score 0):

Or another way is to create a function to remove excess zeros, like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveZeros(
   @value BIGINT
) RETURNS BIGINT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @str = CAST(@value AS NVARCHAR(50))
    WHILE ((LEN(@str)>0) AND (RIGHT(@str,1)=N'0'))
        SET @str = LEFT(@str,LEN(@str)-1)

    RETURN @str
END
```